# problem is select in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

now i have table call files
its have time has this stamp 1260606325
now i tring to get the files which added in the last 7 day

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE time > SUBDATE(NOW(),604800)
```

its return zero

how i can do that

Comment: Use some punctuation marks in yous sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See what [SUBDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) does - it takes its 2. parameter as days by default. It also produces a datetime type in this case, you seem to just have a unix timestamp.

```
mysql> SELECT  SUBDATE(NOW(),604800);
+-----------------------+
| SUBDATE(NOW(),604800) |
+-----------------------+
| 0354-01-27 12:31:30   |
+-----------------------+
```

You'd want

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE from_unixtime(time) > SUBDATE(NOW(),interval 604800 second);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE from_unixtime(time) > SUBDATE(NOW(),7)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE  time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800);
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question more carefully than me and noticing that `time` is of datatype `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1):

you can count time in PHP via `time()-(7*86400)` and use that value?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the unit in the second parameter of SUBDATE:

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE time > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

If you do not specify a unit, days is default so 604800 should be 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE time > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE time > SUBDATE(NOW(), 7)
```

depending on what datatype `time` is of.

You can find information about all the date functions in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

The default unit of the second parameter of `SUBDATE` is days:

> SUBDATE(date,INTERVAL expr unit), SUBDATE(expr,days)